# java - Does directly assigning variable from function call(without new()) raise an exception?

Tags: java

The following code is part of a large project.

Overview is that I am trying to access a database using Spring MVC. I want to update a field based on request and send a response as to what values the database sent back.

Code:

```
@Override
@Transactional

public EmployeeResponse update(EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    UUID empId = UUID.fromString(employeeRequest.getId());
    Employee foundEmployee = employeeRepository.findOne(empId);

    if (foundEmployee != null) {
        foundEmployee.setAddress(employeeRequest.getAddress());
        // similarly set 4 fields of foundEmployee
        emp = employeeRepository.save(foundEmployee);
    }
    EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
    response.setAddress(emp.getAddress());
    // similarly set 4 fields of response

    return response;

}
```

I found that there was no `new Employee()` for `foundEmployee` as there is for `emp`.
I am not sure but I think this'll cause exceptions.
Am I correct?

Also, please tell me what exception I should throw when `foundEmployee` is `null`.

Additional info - this is what the help shows:

```
org.​springframework.​data.​repository.​CrudRepository

public T findOne(ID id)

Retrieves an entity by its id.

Parameters:
id - must not be null.

Returns:
the entity with the given id or null if none found

Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if id is null
```

Comment: what is error throws?

Comment: "*there was no new Employee() for foundEmployee*" => is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's just a reference, no new keyword as in `Car c = new Car()`.

Comment: @bmt Can't say, I don't have the caller methods ready yet(it's a UI).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the line

```
Employee foundEmployee = employeeRepository.findOne(empId);
```

we can presume that `EmployeeRepository.findOne()` will return an instance of `Employee`.  This will not cause a compiler error, and if an exception happens at runtime, it would be inside `findOne()`.

With regard to what you should do in the event of a `null` `foundEmployee`, it is really a design decision you will have to make.  One option would be to have the method return `null` to let the consumer know that the `EmployeeRequest` which was passed in had a serious problem with it.

Another option would be to create your own `Exception` and then throw it in the case of `null` `foundEmployee`.

**Update:**

In light of that you need to pass something back to your UI, another option would be to create an empty `EmployeeReponse` object and return that:

```
EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
response.setAddress(null);
response.setName(null);
```

Make sure that your framework can marshall `null` values into something which is user friendly, for example an empty string for all fields.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the help tooltip.

Comment: The edit doesn't really change what I would say to you in an answer.

Comment: I'll be using a Web UI for create/update/delete so I'd like the user to know via some message that the update failed.

Comment: For now, I've decided to set empty strings as the values. I'll update when I've run the thing and finalized on a method.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and feel free to come back here if you have other concerns.

Comment: As per the code you provided, if foundEmployee is null then address and 4 other fields will set to null.

Comment: @Samurai Yes, I did this intentionally.  Most web frameworks have the ability to marshal a `null` into something which the UI can digest, such as empty string.  So by returning this empty `EmployeeResponse`, the UI can check for this condition.

Comment: Yeah.. csr1992's code also doing the same.. He has empty employee object created and using that obj to return response. 

Employee emp = new Employee();
...
response.setAddress(emp.getAddress());